# Autohiding columns in DynamicJasper

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I want to hide a column while generating the report using *DynamicJasper*.
I am not sure how to do this. I tried to get some function which gives this but I couldn't figure out since I am a to the technology.

Here is my base code:

```
AbstractColumn myColumn = ColumnBuilder.getNew().setColumnProperty(ConstantsClass.REPORT_COLUMN_PROPERTY[0], String.class.getName())
        .setFixedWidth(true)
        .setTitle(ConstantsClass.REPORT_COLUMN_COLUMN_HEAD[0]).setWidth(new Integer(100))
        .setHeaderStyle(myStyle)
        .build();

FastReportBuilder drb = new FastReportBuilder();
drb.addColumn(myColumn);
DynamicReport dr = drb.build();

return dr;
```

Suppose if this column is column B of excel sheet, it should be autohidden while generating report. After column A only C should be displayed. When unhiding, B should be shown.

Comment: And what is a problem? You can add column with method `FastReportBuilder.addColumn` or not - it depends on the logic.

Comment: The samples are [here](http://dynamicjasper.com/documentation-examples/getting-started/)

Comment: Hi Alex, The problem here is columns must be build and kept hidden. Only when they unhide it, it should be shown.. If I am going for a condition in code, I have the option to decide only whether the column has to be build or not.

Comment: Have you found an answer for this by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.Since this is written in java so you can try this.

```
if(ConditionForBColumn) {
AbstractColumn myColumn = ColumnBuilder.getNew().setColumnProperty(ConstantsClass.REPORT_COLUMN_PROPERTY[0], ValueOfB String.class.getName())
    .setFixedWidth(true)
    .setTitle(ConstantsClass.REPORT_COLUMN_COLUMN_HEAD[0]).setWidth(new Integer(100))
    .setHeaderStyle(myStyle)
    .build();
} else {
AbstractColumn myColumn = ColumnBuilder.getNew().setColumnProperty(ConstantsClass.REPORT_COLUMN_PROPERTY[0], String.class.getName())
    .setFixedWidth(true)
    .setTitle(ConstantsClass.REPORT_COLUMN_COLUMN_HEAD[0]).setWidth(new Integer(100))
    .setHeaderStyle(myStyle)
    .build();
}

FastReportBuilder drb = new FastReportBuilder();
drb.addColumn(myColumn);
DynamicReport dr = drb.build();

return dr;
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But this is not helping me since it only allows me to decide whether a column has to be build or not  depending on a condition. My requirement is column must be build and kept as hidden in the excel while printing. Later this should be displayed only when we unhide it.